# Fine-grained access control in web-api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, user-permissions

This is more of an architectural question.  Let's assume we have different types of users logging into a system, and we have a 'customer' entity.  Depending on the permissions of the user, I may want to return different sub-sets of 'customer' properties.  I also might want to allow edits to only certain properties.

Any suggestions on what path to go down?  Here are the options I've thought of thusfar:

1. For each permission level, extend the model - and return the furthest descendant based upon the user permissions.  On the input side, accept the furthest descendant and only cast it to the correct descendant. (Seems like a lot of implicit logic - doesn't seem very elegant)
2. Create different methods (cluttered API, implies more functionality than I might want to expose)

Any other suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is a clear-cut use case for XACML. XACML is the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language. It lets you define fine-grained access control using attributes (about the user, the resource, the environment...).

It's policy-based which means you can write things like:

- users can view customer records that are in the same region as the user
- users can edit customer records they are directly assigned to
- auditors can view customer records for the entire business unit except for sensitive fields

There are several XACML engines out there (WSO2, Heras AF for Java; [Axiomatics for .NET](http://www.axiomatics.com/policy-decision-points.html)).

I've developed quite a few ASP .NET web apps in the .NET 4.0 framework and managed to apply authorization at the presentation tier, the WCF tier, and the data tier. Feel free to ping me for additional information.